Looking for a Nietzsche quote!
I was wondering whether anyone could help me find the source of the following excerpt from Haruhiko Shiratori's Japanese translation of Nietzsche's works: "ニーチェ［超］入門 生きるための哲学." Granted, I can't offer an English translation from a credible source since I only have access to the Korean translation (titled "초역 니체의 말," translated by 박재현), but the content reads as follows:
      052. For death is sure to all
      Live cheerfully for death is sure to all.
      Let us do our utmost for there will come an end.
      The time is now for it is limited.
      Leave the wailing to the opera singers.

The Korean translation is as follows:
      "052. 언젠가는 죽기에
      죽는 것은 이미 정해진 일이기에 명랑하게 살아라.
      언젠가는 끝날 것이기에 온 힘을 다해 맞서자.
      시간은 한정되어 있기에 기회는 늘 지금이다.
      울부짖는 일 따윈 오페라 가수에게나 맡겨라."

I can't seem to find any text of Nietzsche's even remotely similar to the above; I've tried searching for keywords in both English and German. The book as a whole seems to a compilation of Nietzsche's sayings pertaining to his philosophy on life, and the Korean title of the chapter in which that particular quote is classified is "삶에 대하여," meaning "On/About Life."
Please let me know if you're aware of the original text the quote is from, or even just where to look. Thanks in advance!

Are you sure that it is an authentic Nietzsche quote? I have read Nietzsche in full in german (several times, including his estate) and I can tell you that it doesn't sound like Nietzsche, and I can't think of where it could be. To me it sounds more like a pseudo-quote that was foisted on Nietzsche (maybe this came from the translation?). That is done very often. Or a other way to go, can you give more context of the quote?
For research you can look here, it is the only reliable online source that can also be cited. Otherwise, only the critical student edition is used academically. With Nietzsche you also have to pay attention to the sources. http://www.nietzschesource.org/

The only reliable words to look for in German are "opera" and "singers"; so far, I have not seen them in any similar text.

I also don't see any: http://www.nietzschesource.org/SN/search?matchAll=true&word=Oper&standard_search_submission=
